# How to update only a certain parameters of the object?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dao

I have a user object in the database, which has the following parameters: username, password, email, admin(boolean).

I want to change only username and that's it. I don't want to touch other fields. The problem with this is that I need to pass a new value for every parameter of the object.  My current method, which updates user information looks like this:

```
String query = "";
query = "UPDATE users SET username=?, password=?, email=?, admin=? where id=?";
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

try{
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Constant.URL + Constant.DB_NAME, "root", "");
    preparedStatement =  connection.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getUsername() );
    preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getEmail());
    preparedStatement.setBoolean(4, user.isAdmin());
    preparedStatement.setShort(5, id);
    preparedStatement.execute();
} catch (SQLException e){
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    closeResource(connection, preparedStatement);
}
```

My update method in the controller:

```
public static void updateAccountInformation() {
    UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
    short id = Constant.LOGGED_IN_USER_ID;
    System.out.println("Your current account information: ");
    System.out.println("Enter new username: ");
    String username = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter new password: ");
    String password = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter new email: ");
    String email = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Change admin status: ");
    boolean admin = sc.nextBoolean();
    //parameters i need to pass to the user object
    User user = new User();
    try {
        userDao.updatePersonalInfo(user, id);
        System.out.println("User updated successfully!");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
    }
```

What solution you would suggest in this situation?

Comment: Why are you passing other parameters in the UPDATE query? You can do like this :
```query = "UPDATE users SET username=?  where id=?";```

Comment: don't you have a get method from db? You should get the user object from db, and you should set the only parameter you want to change and add it back to db.

Comment: Good point. Originally, i thought that i will have query which could posibilly, if it needs to, update all the parameters or the parameters that i need. But that was a wrong approach. So, as you say, i should have a different query for each parameter?

Comment: Or you can create a method which create a dynamic query for you based on the field you want to update .

Comment: Have a separate query, or do like fatma says and grab the data from the DB before updating the data and adding it back.

Comment: Getting a data to update it , it will be more costlier , since we are making two database calls here . So better create a dynamic query , which will also save you from having redundant code .

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi This is true, though it will take more time to development. Guess it's a question of how you want to spend your resources and set up your architecture? Having the pull then push setup could be advantageous for other methods in the systems depending on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: @TimHunter , I completely agree to your point . That was just an opnion from my side .

Comment: That's a lot of really interesting advice! Thanks a lot, guys. So basically, @HarmandeepSinghKalsi, i should try to create dynamic query regarding this problem?

Comment: Yup @Greddy . You can do that , if it seems feasible to you .